# Get text from specifc class where all classes are the same -Selenium-Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-chromedriver

This is a photo of a webpage that i want to get access on its text, but all of them have the same class
and the same name and the same thing in the whole code

[image]

I tried     `elem = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.className('col-sm-7')).text;`
but it isn't working
Can anyone help me?

Comment: where is the code you have written?

Comment: i tried     elem = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.className('col-sm-7')).text; which "col-sm-7" is a another div. but it's notworking, so

Comment: where did you get the `.col-sm-7` from? please post a complete reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, you want to get the text of one specific `div`. In that case, consider something like this:

```
//A function to be able to do this multiple times
function getDivText(position, className) {
   //getting all divs with the specified class...
   var divs = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
   //and picking the one with the specified position
   var target = divs[position];
   //If the div could be found, return its text
   if(target) {
     return target.innerText;
   } else {
     return ""; //For demonstration purposes, we just return an empty string if the wanted div wasn't found
   } 
   
}
```

and then call the function whenever you need it. For example:
`getDivText("my-div-class", 2);`

Comment: it's selenium question, not normal browser DOM

Comment: It isn't working even when I edit on it a little to work with selenium framework.